# Can I use two ciscoconfparse objects in a single Cisco IOS config file to get specific interfaces

Tags: python-3.x, networking, ciscoconfparse

> Trying to  use two of the conf objects **find_objects_w_child** &
>   **find_objects_wo_child** in a single file.

I need to find out "interfaces" from a Cisco config file which have a specific QoS "service-policy" command configured.

At the same time should not be a part of any Etherchannel.

- Using object "find_objects_w_child" I can get all 'interface' objects having the command "service-policy" configured on it, and
- Using object "find_objects_wo_child" to get all the 'interface' objects which do not have the command "channel-group".

Is it even possible to use these 2 objects on a same config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CiscoConfParse objects do not offer a method that allows you to find objects with specific children, but without other specific children. However, we can utilize a list comprehension to accomplish the same task with the IOSCfgLine object's `re_search_children()` method, as shown below:

```py
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse

parse = CiscoConfParse("ios_cfg.txt")
phys_intfs_w_qos = [obj for obj in parse.find_objects_wo_child(r"^interface", "channel-group") if obj.re_search_children(r"service-policy")]
```

Because regex objects are [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false), the above list comprehension will only return IOSCfgLine objects representing interfaces that do not have `channel-group` configured, but does have `service-policy` configured.